# Russian text is not coming in SMS

Tags: java

I try to send a Russian text from my web application, but when the text is sent to a mobile, it is displayed as "?????????". I have tried UTF-8 and all other possible values of charset for Russian text.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: And the phone can normally read Russian text? If so, would you mind posting some code so we can see what's going on?

Answer (score 4):

SMS text is by default a special 7bit character set, alternatively Unicode UCS2 can be used. Either way, you will need to either encode your text properly before sending or use a gateway that does the encoding for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can transliterate it, i.e. "Привет" => "Privet"

also check the encoding you use. UTF8 is the most common for international characters these days.

Comment: Why transliterate if all modern (by modern I mean 'common') phones support UTF-8?

Comment: To guarantee delivery on any phone of any provider. UTF8 support by all phones not guarantees it's support by all providers SMS centers.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to send SMS, one is with Unicode text another is ASCII.  Unicode has a larger space requirement so messages max length will be smaller.

Make sure you are sending the text in Unicode format.  The SMS gatway API should have documentation on this.

Comment: It's not quite ASCII, it's the 7-bit GSM alphabet which is similar but not identical.